# register form in Laravel redirects to itself without creating an user instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, registration

I've been creating a registration form with Laravel, i used the default Auth one, i only added the category to the form, but i don't know why it keeps redirecting me to the registration form without even creating an user instance, i checked the `User.php` file and added the category to the fallible array also to the migration table of users, but still not working

This is my `register.blade.php` file :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<!-- Fetching the categories from the DATABASE -->

<?php 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    $categories = DB::table('static_categories')->get();
?>

<!-- **************************************************** -->

@section('content')

<div class="container">

    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="cat" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Category') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                {{-- <input id="category" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('category') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="category" value="{{ old('category') }}" required autofocus> --}}
                                <select id="cat" class="custom-select" required>
                                    <option selected>Choose Category</option>
                                    @for($i=0;$i<count($categories); $i++)
                                        <option value="{{$categories[$i]->cat_id}}">{{$categories[$i]->categoryname}}</option>
                                    @endfor
                                </select>

                                @if ($errors->has('cat'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('cat') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And this is my migration file of users :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsers extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->integer('cat')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('cat')->references('cat_id')->on('static_categories');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

And this is my registerController file :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'cat' => 'required|integer'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'cat' => $data['cat'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance ! Don't mind the bad way of posting this question, this is my first time !

Comment: show me your route file for get, store register form, show me you store function for `route('register')`?? or you are using laravel default functions ??

Comment: It's fine thanks ! I only missed the "name" attribute in my "select" tag !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are missing the name of the category field**.

```
<select name="cat"></select>
```

That's why it is not going in request. In laravel, you must give name to input field otherwise it will be omitted.
I will suggest that whenever you face this situation then dump the data e.g.

`dd($request->all()` ;

and see if required data is coming or not.

**Answer to your question is:** 
laravel is redirecting because you have required category field in validations and you are not sending it to server because field name is missing. You could see the error if you added this code below select tag

```
@if ($errors->has('cat'))
     <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
          <strong>{{ $errors->first('cat') }}</strong>
     </span>
@endif
```